# where does an automatic object live in( with a demo )

Tags: c++, assembly

I want to do some research in the memory management of c++ and it's implementations like g++, vc++.

**The first question is where is an automatic object(local object) live in?(built-in type, user-defined type, STL...)**

I think the built-in type is stored in stack which is done in the compiling step. And what's the fact that for a user-defined type? I see somewhere before that the STL data type is always in the heap memory. So I wrote a tiny function, compiled with g++, disassembled using objdump, to see what the compiler really did.

```
#include <string>

void autovar(){
    std::string s;
}
```

And the result of disassembling is as follows:

```
00000000 <__Z7autovarv>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp //push the old frame pointer 
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp //ebp point to the old
   3:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp//allocate stack space
   6:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax//param or something??
   9:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
   c:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   11 <__Z7autovarv+0x11>
  11:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  14:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  17:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1c <__Z7autovarv+0x1c>
  1c:   c9                      leave
  1d:   c3                      ret
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   90                      nop
```

**So I can understand the first 3 lines, I need some help to understand the rest**

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Lea is load-effective-address but it maybe used for just calculations.

Comment: Afaik, when you write a function and you make a local variable, it goes on the stack, so your variable `s` will exist on the stack and will no longer exist when this stack frame is exited.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Standard disclaimer: an implementation *could* work entirely differently, but most on an x86 or similar, will probably act roughly as described below.

When you define an object with auto storage duration, that object *itself* is going to be allocated on the stack. So, let's consider a somewhat simplified version of a vector:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class vector {
    T *data;
    size_t currently_used;
    size_t allocated;
public:
    // ...
};
```

So, when we allocate a `vector`, that object *itself* (the storage for the `data` pointer, `currently_used` and `allocated` counters) gets allocated on the stack.

Assuming a typical 32-bit machine where pointers and size_ts are 32-bits each, that'll mean 12 bytes of space on the stack. For simpler types (e.g., `int` or `long`) and *conceivably* even for something like `vector`, we'd expect to see locals allocated in registers in quite a few cases. The compiler chooses which to allocate in registers based on (guesses at) which are likely to be used the most. On a machine like a SPARC or an Itanium that has *lots* of registers, we can expect *most* local/auto variables to be in registers. On an x86 we have enough fewer registers that stack usage is pretty common (though x86-64 doubles the available registers, which helps quite a bit).

The vector itself then uses the `Allocator` object to get storage elsewhere (typically, but not necessarily the free store) to store the data you care about (i.e., the elements you store *in* the vector).

Looking at the specific details of the code you included: it looks to me like most of the rest of the code is invoking the constructor and destructor for your `std::string` object. Unfortunately, you've used the horrible AT&T syntax, which makes it nearly unreadable.

Comment: It's enlightening. So string is a special vector and is analogous. And typically all auto object defined without using new is in the stack, is it correct? BTW: what's the difference between free store and heap?

Comment: @zoujyjs: Anything that's auto storage class (i.e., not using new *and* not a global) will typically be on the stack or in a register. The usual terminology is that the "free store" is what's managed by `new`/`delete`, while the heap is what's managed by `malloc`/`free` (and `realloc`, `calloc`, etc.) Pretty much the same capabilities though.

Answer (score 6):

Automatic variables generally are allocated on stack, but their implementations may, of course, use other memory. In case of standard containers, they will use dynamic memory allocation or whatever `Allocator` user supplies. So, in the example, `s` object is located on stack, but it's data could be elsewhere (if it wasn't empty).

Your assembly commented:

```
00000000 <__Z7autovarv>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp //push the old frame pointer 
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp //ebp point to the old
   3:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp //allocate stack space
   6:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
        //store address of `s` (which is 12 bytes below %ebp) in eax
   9:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp) //put it on a stack (argument)
   c:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   11 <__Z7autovarv+0x11> //call constructor
  11:   8d 45 f4                lea    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  14:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  17:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   1c <__Z7autovarv+0x1c> //call destructor
  1c:   c9                      leave //restore esp and ebp
  1d:   c3                      ret //return
  1e:   90                      nop
  1f:   90                      nop
```

Comment: That is to say, s is still in stack, and it's address is 12 bytes below %ebp? But why 12 bytes and what if I change s dynamically.

Comment: @zoujyjs, I added some text. 12 bytes is explained by Jerry Coffin - pointer, length and allocated length - on 32-bit machine all of them are usually 4 bytes long.